# Get items according to the first letter

Tags: javascript, list

I am trying to get items according the first letter e.g if the items first letter is A I wand that item to appear in divA e.t.c

my code:

```
function onS() {
    var lstString = ""; 
    var Enum = listItems.getEnumerator();
    while (Enum.moveNext())
    {
        var currentItem = Enum.get_current();
        lstString += "<br/>" + currentItem.get_item("Title").substring(0,1);//here I check the first letter.

        if (lstString = "A") {
            $("#divA").html(); //here I want to get that item
        }  
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you can do it like this :

```
if( currentItem.get_item("Title").substring(0,1).toUpperCase() == 'A' )
// or
if( currentItem.get_item("Title")[0].toUpperCase() == 'A' )
```

**Note** : You need to use `==` instead `=` into an `if` condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
var word = 'Aword';
var firstLetter = word[0];
var selector = '#div' + firstLetter;
var container = $(selector);

container.html(word);
```

Do you mean something like that?
Here is the working example: http://jsfiddle.net/9rky2nwh/